# return SQL only for Tuesdays

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that return a result between two dates(last  4 weeks) and between 2pm and 12am :
How to filter to return only Tuesdays ?

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM   monitor_files 
    WHERE  trfr_type IN ( 'FTE', 'SFTP' ) 
           AND create_time >= To_timestamp('20170718 140000', 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') 
           AND create_time < To_timestamp('20170819 000000', 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') 
           AND trfr_status = 'C'
```

This one worked for me (thanks Caius Jard):

```
select * 
from monitor_files 
where trfr_type in ('FTE', 'SFTP') 
      AND CREATE_TIME >= TO_TIMESTAMP('20170718 140000', 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') 
      AND CREATE_TIME < TO_TIMESTAMP('20170819 000000', 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') 
      AND TRFR_STATUS ='C' AND to_char(create_time, 'dy') = 'tue' 
      AND extract(hour from CAST(create_time as timestamp))  BETWEEN 14 AND 23
```

Thanks.

Comment: To_timestamp() is a Oracle built in function. if you execute that in sql server you would get To_timestamp' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: Yes @OLIVER.KOO that's nice. OP, you should be able to use EXTRACT with DAY_OF_WEEK in a similar manner. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37483_01/server.751/es_eql/src/ceql_functions_date_extract.html

Comment: And I just noticed that my above query gives me times after midnight, I want only between 2pm and midnight.

Comment: I just added :    AND EXTRACT('TimeStamp', DAY_OF_WEEK) = 5  but got   ORA-00904: "DAY_OF_WEEK": invalid identifier

Comment: Update the question/code in the original post if you make any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add into where

```
to_char(create_time,'d') = 3
```

Comment: The result of this query varies on current user session Nls_TERRITORY settings.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following where clause predicates:

```
AND to_char(create_time, 'dy') = 'tue'
AND extract(hour from CAST(create_time as timestamp))  BETWEEN 14 AND 23
```

As far as I know in oracle, extract cannot be used to get the day of the week. It also cannot be used to get the hour of a date time type, it has to be another type such as timestamp - if your create_time is a timestamp you can omit the cast.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm#SQLRF00639

Comment: The result of this query varies on current user session Nls_Date_LANGUAGE settings.

Comment: WD makes a good point; you may need to vary the word 'tue' to suit the language of your install target. If your system will be installed in multiple locales, you might need to replace 'tue' with a to_char(to_date('19700106', 'yyyymmdd'), 'dy',) Or some other particular date known to be a Tuesday, like 6th Jan 1970

Comment: I think the better approach is to use the nlsparam parameter https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm#SQLRF06129

Comment: I am a newbie in SQL, the solution of Caius Jard worked for me, I don't understand Wernfried Domscheit 's comment.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I'd be happy for you to edit my post to include a suitable example :)

Answer (score 0):

In general `to_char(create_time, 'd') = 3` and `to_char(create_time, 'dy') = 'tue'` are working but they depend on current user session NLS settings.

`to_char(..., 'd')` returns week day. However, the first weekday depends on `NLS_TERRITORY`. For example in America first day of week is Sunday, whereas in Europe first day of week is Monday. In Arabic cultures the Saturday is typically considered as first day of week. So, unless you check/set `NLS_TERRITORY` the result of `to_char(..., 'd')` is not determined, see examples:

```
alter session set nls_territory = 'america';
select to_char(sysdate,'d') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'D')
6

alter session set nls_territory = 'germany';
select to_char(sysdate,'d') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'D')
5
```

Same applies for `to_char(..., 'dy')`. I depends on `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`, see example:

```
alter session set nls_date_language = 'american';
select to_char(sysdate-3,'day') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-3,'DAY')
tuesday  

alter session set nls_date_language = 'french';
select to_char(sysdate-3,'day') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-3,'DAY')
mardi
```

In order to be independent from `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` you should use

```
to_char(create_time,'dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american') = 'tue'
```

Note, when `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` is not set then the value is derived from `NLS_TERRITORY`. In case `NLS_TERRITORY` is not set either then the value is derived from `NLS_LANG`, see [Setting Up a Globalization Support Environment](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch3globenv.htm)